# Finding the local extrema for $x^{1/5}(x+3)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$x^{1/5}(x+3)$$

I know the general steps to finding local extremas using the first derivative test. I determined the critical points for this curve which is $x=-\frac{1}{2}, 0$ The interval $(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2})$ is increasing, $(-\frac{1}{2},0)$ is decreasing, and $(0,\infty)$ is increasing. Now I know that a local maximum occurs when an interval changes from increasing to decreasing. However the online homework says that a local maximum does not exist for this curve. Am I missing something here? I checked the curve on WolframAlpha and there seemed to be a cusp, is there a special condition I don't know about?

Comment: Please explain how you found the critical points and intervals of increase and decrease, as they do not agree with what I've found.

Comment: I solved the derivative for 0. $\frac{3(2x+1)}{5x^{4/5}}=0$ the critical points I got were $x=-1/2 and 0$. I then subdivided the interval and tested points to see which interval increases or decreases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$y'(x) = \dfrac{6x + 3}{5x^{4/5}}.$$

$$y'(x) = 0 \iff x = -1/2$$

$x = -1/2$ is indeed a critical point, and and it is a local minimum. The vertical tangent exists $x = 0$ because the derivative is not defined at $x = 0$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} y'(x) = -\infty, \quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to 0^+} y'(x)/5= +\infty$$

We can see the local minimum, and the vertical tangent using the "real valued roots" option in the following graph from Wolfram Alpha.

[image]

Comment: @amWhy When I use $-1$ to test for increase/decrease, it ended as increasing. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, the online homework says that there is no local maximum. However there is a local minimum at the point $(-0.5,-2.176)$. I am really confused :(. I am sure it says local maximum. *Edit WolframAlpha also says that no local maximum exists.

Comment: @StevenN Try hitting the "Use the real-valued root button".

Comment: I think you just let the graph confuse you! By the way, you can go straight to the real-valued version using notation like `plot surd(x,5)(x+3)` - crazy, eh??

Comment: @Mark Thanks...yes, indeed, I let the graph confuse me! Thanks for the tip...That will certainly be helpful to use in the future! You would think Wolfram would default to the real root? Crazy, indeed!

Comment: I am not worried about the graph but more worried about my work. I am sure I have done the math right The interval (−∞,−12) is increasing, (−12,0) is decreasing, and (0,∞) is increasing. I subdivided the interval using the critical points.

Comment: @StevenN Why -12?  Looking at amWhy's derivative, I see critical points at -1/2 and zero - not at -12.

Comment: I am sorry, the 12 are supposed to be 1/2. I am a bit rusty dealing with fractional exponents. Do you know where I can review for fractional exponents? ie. 1^(4/5) and -1^(4/5).

Comment: Steven, what is the value of the derivative at $-1$? if the derivative is negative, then the function is decreasing there.

Comment: I got a positive number when I evaluated the derivative at $-1$.

Comment: It should be negative. It evaluates to $\dfrac{-6 + 3}{5} = \dfrac {-3}{5}.$ Note: the denominator:$\quad 5\cdot (-1)^{4/5} = 5\cdot ((-1)^{1/5})^4 = 5\cdot(-1)^4 = 5\cdot 1 = 5$

Comment: Oh... I entered it into a calculator without parenthesis and it always evaluated to a $-1$. So if I were to do this by hand, I can usually rewrite the fraction exponents like what you did?

Comment: Yes...when you have an exponent $\frac ab$, and $b$ is positive, then you can write $x^{a/b} = (x^{1/b})^a$

Answer (score 0):

No, it has a local max where you say it does; the homework seems to be mistaken.